# Loop through multiple arrays, combining to single array,maintaining indexes within the subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays

Bit of a long winded title but I'll try to explain what I want to do. 
Basically I've got a number of arrays that I want to combine into a single array. The trouble is, I need to loop through the items in the subarrays and add them 1 at a time and maintain the order. The end goal is I want to display the data back paged. I've got a simple example below that I will use to try and convey what I mean. This isn't an alphabetical sort i.e **h** should not be before **i** in the bottom example.

So in my example I know I want 3 pages of results. The first page should have 4 items, the second page 4 items and the third only 1 item.

I can do the final paging myself as I will have an array of all inner items at the end of it "**mix**", but I can't work out how to loop through my arrays and add them in how I need.

I've got the page variable upfront but I'm not sure how to structure the loop. I think I basically need to loop through each subarray and pop() the first item off, then loop through the next one, pop() the first item and so forth. But somewhere I need to check how many items are left in each subarray.

For instance if I only had array "one" I would in theory have 2 pages the first containing a,c,e,i and the second only k, this one is obviously simple enough as I just check the length of the only array.

But if I added in another array "third" [1,2,3,4,5] then I would expect the mix array to be ['a','b',1,'c','d',2...etc]; Each of these arrays could in theory have different lengths so then I would obviously skip an empty value.

```
 var one = ['a','c','e','i','k'];
 var two = ['b','d','f','h'];

 var all = [one,two];
 var pagecount = 3;
 var mix = [];

 for(var i = 0; i< all.length; i++){
     var area = all[i];    
 }
 // End result should be mix = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','i','h','k'];
```

I've tried to word this as best as I can, but I'm struggling to get my head around how to explain this myself! Unfortunately in the real world I have no control over the data/size of the data arrays.

Any questions or if something is not clear then please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for (var i = 0; all.length !== 0; i++) {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < all.length) {
        if (i >= all[j].length) {
            all.splice(j, 1);
        } else {
            mix.push(all[j][i]);
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

On each iteration of the outer loop we increase `i` by one, this will be the index in each array to grab an item from.  For the inner loop we will do one of the following:

- If the index `i` is beyond the maximum index for the array `all[j]` we are done with that array so it is removed using `all.splice(j, 1)`.  We do not advance `j` because `all[j]` will refer to the next array after the previous element at that location was removed.
- Otherwise we add the item `all[j][i]` to `mix` and increase `j` by one to move to the next array on the next iteration.

The outer loop doesn't stop until there are no arrays left in `all`, which will happen when `i` has exceeded the length of the longest array.

For example with three arrays all of different lengths:

```
var one = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var two = ['a', 'b'];
var three = ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
var all = [one, two, three];
var mix = [];
// after running the above loop mix will have the following contents:
// [1, "a", "U", 2, "b", "V", 3, "W", 4, "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Comment: How would this work if you wanted to "Foo" before/ "bar" after one[i]? output would be: [foo1bar, "a", "U", foo2bar, "b", "V", foo3bar, "W", foo4bar, "X", "Y", "Z"]   ...could you change it to" `var all = ["foo" + one + "bar", two, three];`

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the inner index in the outer loop, and the arrays in the inner loop:

```
for (var i = 0, cont = true; cont; i++) {
  cont = false;
  for (j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
    if (i < all[j].length) {
      mix.push(all[j][i]);
      cont = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a simple merge function. You could do it like this

```
var one = ['a','c','e','i','k'];
var two = ['b','d','f','h'];
var mix = new Array();
var merging = true;
var index = 0;
while (merging) {
    merging = false;
    if (index < one.length) {
        mix[mix.length] = one[index];
        merging = true;
    }
    if (index < two.length) {
        mix[mix.length] = two[index];
        merging = true;
    }

    // add if blocks for arrays three, four, etc...

    index++;
}
```

This can be expanded for any number of arrays by simply adding another if block inside the loop

Comment: I actually like the other answers better haha. I just immediately thought of this answer because we had to prove its correctness in a CS course. So at least I know it works :)